# Using melt / cast with variables of uneven length in R

Tags: r, casting, reshape, melt

I'm working with a large data frame that I want to pivot, so that variables in a column become rows across the top.

I've found the reshape package very useful in such cases, except that the cast function defaults to fun.aggregate=length.  Presumably this is because I'm performing these operations by "case" and the number of variables measured varies among cases.

I would like to pivot so that missing variables are denoted as "NA"s in the pivoted data frame.

So, in other words, I want to go from a molten data frame like this:

```
Case | Variable | Value
 1         1        2.3
 1         2        2.1
 1         3        1.3
 2         1        4.3
 2         2        2.5
 3         1        1.8
 3         2        1.9
 3         3        2.3
 3         4        2.2
```

To something like this:

```
Case | Variable 1 | Variable 2 | Variable 3 | Variable 4
 1         2.3          2.1          1.3         NA
 2         4.3          2.5          NA          NA
 3         1.8          1.9          2.3         2.2
```

The code dcast(data,...~Variable) again defaults to fun.aggregate=length, which does not preserve the original values.

Thanks for your help, and let me know if anything is unclear!

Comment: Maybe you should try `dcast` in `reshape2`? When I run your `dcast` statement using reshape2, I get your desired output (i.e. with the NA values).

Comment: Agree with @Joran -- `reshape2` is the way to go

Comment: Hmm, it appears I made my example too simple, because it does indeed work with that statement.  It won't for the large dataset with which I'm working, though.  Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 5):

It is just a matter of including all of the variables in the `cast` call. Reshape expects the `Value` column to be called `value`, so it throws a warning, but still works fine. The reason that it was using `fun.aggregate=length` is because of the missing `Case` in the formula. It was aggregating over the values in `Case`.

Try: `cast(data, Case~Variable)`

```
data <- data.frame(Case=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3),
  Variable=c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4),
  Value=c(2.3,2.1,1.3,4.3,2.5,1.8,1.9,2.3,2.2))

cast(data,Case~Variable)
Using Value as value column.  Use the value argument to cast to override this choice
  Case   1   2   3   4
1    1 2.3 2.1 1.3  NA
2    2 4.3 2.5  NA  NA
3    3 1.8 1.9 2.3 2.2
```

Edit: as a response to the comment from @Jon. What do you do if there is one more variable in the data frame?

```
data <- data.frame(expt=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
               func=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3),
               variable=c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4),
               value=c(2.3,2.1,1.3,4.3,2.5,1.8,1.9,2.3,2.2))

cast(data,expt+variable~func)
  expt variable   1   2   3
1    1        1 2.3 4.3  NA
2    1        2 2.1  NA  NA
3    1        3 1.3  NA  NA
4    2        1  NA  NA 1.8
5    2        2  NA 2.5 1.9
6    2        3  NA  NA 2.3
7    2        4  NA  NA 2.2
```

Comment: I'm still trying to understand this fun.aggregate statement.  I have a molten data frame with the column headers "Expt", "function.","variable"," and "value".  I want to pivot the variables under "function." across the top as a function of "Expt" and "variable".  So my function is dcast(data,Expt+variable~function.).  I still get the "Aggregation function is missing: defaulting to length" error, though...any thoughts?

Comment: @Jon, If those four columns are all that you have in your melted `data` data frame, the `cast(data, Expt + variable ~ function)` should work. If you edit your question with the new information, I will try to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. It does not use the package or function you mention, but it could be of use. Suppose your data frame is called `df`:

```
M <- matrix(NA,
            nrow = length(unique(df$Case)),
            ncol = length(unique(df$Variable))+1,
            dimnames = list(NULL,c('Case',paste('Variable',sort(unique(df$Variable))))))
irow <- match(df$Case,unique(df$Case))
icol <- match(df$Variable,unique(df$Variable)) + 1
ientry <- irow + (icol-1)*nrow(M)
M[ientry] <- df$Value
M[,1] <- unique(df$Case)
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the warning message, you could subset the data frame according to another variable, i.e a categorical variable having three levels a,b,c.  Because in you current data for category a it has 70 cases, for b 80 cases, c has 90. Then the cast function doesn't know how to aggregate them.

Hope this helps.